# Data.frame copy and paste values based on a condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following structure/values and would like to go through the data frame (by row) and paste the values from the first column ("One") into the cells of the other columns only if they are not NA:

**My data:**

```
  One         Two    Three  Four
1 Bar_2_Foo    NA    NA     1
2 Mur_4_Doo     1    NA     2
3 Bur_3_Hoo    NA     1    NA
```

**What I would like to achieve:**

```
  One         Two    Three  Four
1 Bar_2_Foo    NA    NA     Bar_2_Foo_1
2 Mur_4_Doo    Mur_4_Doo_1    NA     Mur_4_Doo_2
3 Bur_3_Hoo    NA     Bur_3_Hoo_1    NA
```

Any ideas how to achieve this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: R base, it can be improved, `cbind(data[1],apply(data[,2:4],2,function(i)ifelse(is.na(i), NA, paste(data[,1],i,sep="_"))))`

Comment: Thanks ! This looks exactly what I need. R starts and seems to iterate through the rows (judged by the time it takes), but the resulting file does not show any changes.  I think the function works but it cant identify the NA. If that makes any sense.

Comment: Ok, I just got what I did wrong. @S Rivero. This worked ! Great. Thanks a million.

Comment: @SRivero what if we want to not convert to matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
mutate_at(data, Two:Four, function(i){
  ifelse(!is.na(i), paste0(One, "_", i), i) } )
```